# Im having an issue, verifying if fields were filled

Tags: php

I have a form, and Im trying to verify if the user fill all fields:

```
if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']))
 {
   echo '<span>Please fill all fields!</span>';
 }
```

And everything is working fine, When I didn´t fill a field, I got the alert message.

But now I introduce a new "input file" on my form, to insert PDFs, and I also entered this field in my validation:

`if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']) || empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])`)

And now, the thumb and other form fields are working fine, when I dont fill, I got the alert message, **but with my pdf field**, When I dont fill this field, **I never get the alert message**.

Here I have my form:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

       <label class="line">
            <span>Image:</span>
            <input type="file" class="fileinput" name="thumb"/>
        </label>   

        <label class="line">
            <span>Title:</span>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="" />
        </label>

        <label class="line">
            <span>Pdfs<input type="file"  name="pdf[]" size="60" multiple="multiple"  accept="application/pdf"/></span>
        </label> 

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sendForm" />

 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array "pdf[]" compared to "thumb". You could check the first element of this array [0]:

```
if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']) || empty($_FILES['pdf'][0]['tmp_name']))
```

It is the array elements (`$_FILES['pdf'][0]`, `$_FILES['pdf'][1]`, etc.) that would contain the 'tmp_name'.

---

My mistake, the array is the other way round `$_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'][0]`.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. But now Im having a different problem, I have always the alert message, even when I fill all fields :SS

Comment: Break the if-statement across three lines, and three different echoes, so that you can determine which condition is causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I did that now, and the problem is always in the third, the $_FILES['pdf'][0] one.

Comment: Try without the `accept` attribute and in different browsers. Otherwise, use `print_r($_FILES['pdf'])` to discover what is in this array.

Comment: There is also the possibility that your web host isn't configured to accept pdfs, or the file size is too big.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy G, but if I use only pdf in input name and not pdf[]...it works fine! So the problem is really the way Im doing the verification..

Comment: I've added a correction to my answer, the array is the other way round `$_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'][0]`. Soz. but print_r the whole array to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks for all your attention! It was really that, the position of array in the end. I also had not realized that..thanks :)